How many four digit numbers (including leading zeros) have exactly one 8 and no digits appearing two times?
I am trying to best interpret this question.
If I interpret this as no digit appears exactly two times then I used the inclusion exclusion principle:
There are $4(9^3)$ four digit numbers that have exactly one eight.
There are $(9)(4)(3)(8)$ four digit numbers with exactly one eight and exactly two of another digit (9 digits we could choose to have twice, 4 positions we could put the one eight in, 3 positions we could put those two digits in, 8 digits left to fill the last position). By the principle of inclusion exclusion there are $4(9^3) - (8)(4)(3)(8)$ four digit numbers with exactly one 8 and not exactly two of any other digit.
If I interpret this as we can only have one of each digit then the answer is simply (4)(9)(8)(7) because we have four positions for the eight, then 9, 8, 7 choices for the remaining digits.
Is this the right approach? If so, which one does the question intend me to use?

In you first approach you forgot the numbers where a non-$8$ digit repeats three times. There are $4\times 9$ of them. Hence the answer is $$4\times 9^3-4\times 9\times3\times 8-4\times9.$$
This is equal to $$4\times 9\times 8\times 7.$$
